# How to set the size of STL queue in class constructor

Tags: c++, stl

A class has a queue and I need to set the queue size in the constructor of the class. Is this possible?

Just an idea what I want to do:

```
class Test
{
  queue<int> age_queue;     
  Test(int queue_size):age_queue(queue_size){}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
class Test
{
  queue<int> age_queue;     
  Test(int queue_size):age_queue(deque<int>(queue_size)){}
};
```